# Clojure defmacro loses metadata

Tags: macros, clojure, type-hinting

I am trying to create a little Clojure macro that `def`s a String with a type hint:

```
(defmacro def-string [name value]
  `(def ^String ~name ~value))

(def-string db-host-option "db-host")
```

When I `macroexpand` it, the type hint is lost:

```
(macroexpand '(def-string db-host-option "db-host"))
;=> (def db-host-option "db-host")
```

Never mind the wisdom of type hinting this.

Why is the macro losing the metadata? How do I write this macro, or any that includes metadata?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`^` is a reader macro. `defmacro` never gets to see it. The hint is put on the list `(unquote name)`. Compare for example `(meta ^String 'x)` with `(meta ' ^String x)` to see the effect.

You need to put the hint on the symbol.

```
(defmacro def-string
  [name value]
  `(def ~(vary-meta name assoc :tag `String) ~value))
```

And the usage:

```
user=> (def-string foo "bar")
#'user/foo
user=> (meta #'foo)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name foo, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :line 5, :tag java.lang.String}
```

Comment: Ahh! Of course, reader macros get evaluated before defmacros. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Metadata doesn't show up in a macroexpand since it's supposed to be "invisible".

If the macro is correct (which it isn't) you should be able to call (meta #'db-host-option) to inspect the meta data on the var.

Note that (def sym ...) inserts metadata on the var that it receives from the symbol. But ^Tag ~name sets the meta data on ~name (unquote name), not on the passed in symbol bound to name. It can't do anything else since ^Tag ... processing is done by the reader, which is already finished once macro expansion starts.

You want something like

```
(defmacro def-string [name value]
  `(def ~(with-meta name {:tag String}) ~value))


user> (def-string bar 1)
#'user/bar
user> (meta #'bar)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name bar, :file "NO_SOURCE_FILE", :line 1, :tag java.lang.String}
```