# How do you convert a expression into a predicate? (Clojure)

Tags: clojure, expression, predicate

Given that I have a expression of the form

```
'(map? %)
```

How do I convert it into something like

```
'#(map? %)
```

So that I can ultimately expand it into something like

```
'(apply #(map? %) value)
```

I think I should use a macro in some way, but am not sure how.

Comment: Do you mean that you have `(map? %)` stored as data, i.e. as a list with two symbols?

Comment: yes, I am really attempting to do this in a macro, I think I will quote everything to indicate what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#` invokes a reader macro and reader macros expansion happen before normal macros expansion happens. So to do what you have mentioned, you need to go through the reader in your macro using `read-string` as shown below.

```
(defmacro pred [p v] 
     (let [s# (str \# (last p))] 
         `(apply ~(read-string s#) ~v)))



user=> (pred '(map? %) [{}])
true
user=> (pred '(map? %) [[]])
false
```

In case the data i.e the predicate expression is available at runtime then you need to use a function (which is more flexible then macro).

```
(defn pred [p v] 
   (let [s (read-string (str \# p))] 
      (eval `(apply ~s ~v))))

user=> (map #(pred % [12]) ['(map? %)'(even? %)])
(false true)
```

Comment: ...but why use the reader macro at all? why not just use `fn` directly?

Comment: May be because he want the input predicates without fn signature and using %1 %2 and so on for parameter names. This question is very specific and doesn't provide the whole picture which may lead to a better solution overall

Comment: good point, I hadn't seen that since his source data contains a reference to `%`, it seems designed to work with `#(...)`.

Comment: Wow, very interesting. I was sure I was missing something, as I could not figure out how to put the # in place using the normal macro mechanism. The reason I ask this is because I notice that the :post key in the prepost-args? in the defn argument list takes a vector of expressions. I was curious how the expressions were being evaluated, since they were being declared as expressions, and not as anonymous functions.

Answer (score 3):

`#(...)` is a reader macro. I don't think that you can generate expression with reader macro. For example `'#(map? %)` will automatically expand into `(fn* [p1__352#] (map? p1__352#))` or something similar.

Here's a somewhat [relevant discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754429/clojure-defmacro-loses-metadata) on other reader macro.

Would it be possible to change format of the predicate? If it looked something like:

```
'([arg1] (map? arg1))
```

Then it would be trivial to make a function form it:

```
(cons 'fn '([arg1] (map? arg1)))

(def pred (eval (cons 'fn '([p](map? p)))))
#'predicate.core/pred

(pred {})
true

(pred 10)
false
```

---

Now please don't hate me for what I'm going to post next. I wrote an overly simplified version of the function reader macro:

```
(defn get-args [p]
  (filter #(.matches (str %) "%\\d*")
          (flatten p)))

(defn gen-args [p]
  (into [] 
        (into (sorted-set) 
              (get-args p))))

(defmacro simulate-reader [p]
  (let [arglist (gen-args p)
        p (if (= (str (first p)) "quote")
            (second p)
            p)]
    (list 'fn (gen-args p) p)))
```

Using it is very straight-forward:

```
((simulate-reader '(map? %)) {}) ; -> true
; or without quote
((simulate-reader (map? %)) {})

; This also works:
((simulate-reader '(+ %1 %2)) 10 5) ; -> 15
```

The difference with the other solution given by @Ankur is:

1. I like mine less. I just thought it was a fun thing to do.
2. Does not require conversion to string and then applying reader macro to it.