# Why does `(def ^:private name 1 ) eval to (def namespace/name 1)?

Tags: clojure

Why does this:

```
`(def ^:private name 1 )
```

evaluate to:

```
(def namespace/name 1)
```

and not to this:

```
(def ^:private namespace/name 1)
```

i'm just trying to write a little macro:

```
(defmacro def- [name val] `(def ^:private ~name ~val))
```

but it expands to:

```
(macroexpand-1 `(def- foo 12))
=> (def namespace/foo 12)
```

Comment: Do you know how metadata works?

Comment: no sorry, maybe i should dig this way, thank you

Comment: I maybe wrong but I think you need `with-meta` here. http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/with-meta

Comment: You should use the regular quote with `macroexpand-1`; with it your call becomes `(macroexpand-1 '(def- foo 12))`, which returns the actual expansion of `(def foo 12)`. With the backtick, the form that gets macroexpanded is `(namespace/def- namespace/foo 12)`; it is this form that expands to `(def namespace/foo 12)`, which is an error (the "name" symbol passed to `def` may not be namespace-qualified). The metadata issue is as described in kotarak's answer to [the question linked to be Guillermo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754429/clojure-defmacro-loses-metadata).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [clojure defmacro loses metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754429/clojure-defmacro-loses-metadata), since `^` is a reader macro.

And `:private` is [symbol metadata](http://clojure.org/metadata), so it's lost.

Look at the answer to the question on the first link for a solution.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, please don't write an answer, but leave a comment or flag the question. At 3000 rep, you'll be able to cast close votes for this.

Comment: Ack'ed, question is posed different so not exactly a duplicate, improved the answer to close the gap between the question asked here and the solution provided in the original link.

Comment: This is true but not relevant to the problem he's actually seeing - misusing metadata in this way does cause his `:private` to be lost, but as Michal says in his comment, the main issue is that he's using `\`` in his call to `macroexpand`, instead of `'`, so the extra `namespace/` qualifier is added in before his macro even sees the name.