# Attempt to add annotation to defrecord defined class in macro

Tags: clojure, macros, annotations, quartzite

I'm attempting to create a macro similar to the Quartzite defjob macro that creates the Job class with the @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation added to it.  The code works from the repl, but not inside the macro.

This works...

```
user=> (defrecord ^{DisallowConcurrentExecution true} YYY []
  #_=>   org.quartz.Job
  #_=>   (execute [this context]
  #_=>            (println "whoosh!")))
user.YYY
user=> (seq (.getAnnotations YYY))
(#<$Proxy3 @org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution()>)
```

...but this does not.

```
(defmacro defncjob
  [jtype args & body]
  `(defrecord ^{DisallowConcurrentExecution true} ~jtype []
              org.quartz.Job
              (execute [this ~@args]
                ~@body)))
```

After Rodrigo's suggestion, here is a way to make it work.

```
(defmacro defdcejob
  [jtype args & body]
  `(defrecord ~(vary-meta jtype assoc `DisallowConcurrentExecution true) []
     org.quartz.Job
     (execute [this ~@args]
       ~@body)))
```

Comment: could you run `(macroexpand-1 '(defncjob XXX [context] (println "whooosh"))) and include the result ? (this is the first step in *every* macro problem)

Comment: You can't use a reader macro (^) inside a macro. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754429/clojure-defmacro-loses-metadata

Comment: @RodrigoTaboada Please put that in an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `^` [reader macro](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) inside macros. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754429/clojure-defmacro-loses-metadata) similar question.