# how to preserve meta tags in defmacro

Tags: clojure

How can macros be defined to preserve metadata information?

```
(defmacro defdynamic
  [name val]
  (let [dname (symbol (str "*" name "*"))]
    `(def ^:dynamic ~dname ~val)))

(defdynamic hello 1)
```

will give a warning:

```
Warning: *hello* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically
rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate
^:dynamic *hello* or change the name.
```

and the var will not be dynamic

```
(:dynamic (meta #'*hello*))
=> nil
```

Comment: Explanation in this Q and A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7754429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying meta in the wrong place.

```
(defmacro defdynamic
    [name val]
    (let [dname (-> (str "*" name "*")
                    (symbol)
                    (with-meta {:dynamic true}))]
        `(def ~dname ~val)))
```

`^:dynamic ~dname` does not work because it is equivalent to 
`(with-meta (unquote dname) {:dynamic true})`. So meta is applied to unquote itself, not to the end result.

Comment: sweet. what's the difference? (apart from the obvious in that one works and the other doesn't). as in why does it work?

Comment: ie. why doesn't this work: `(def ~^:dynamic dname ~val) ?

Comment: @zcaudate Unquote causes the symbol to get evaluated. Metadata on a symbol has no impact on how it is evaluated: it resolves to whatever it's bound to. Rather, you want to evaluate the symbol (yielding another symbol), and then attach new metadata to the result.